# jQuery not working in my HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am stuck with an issue ..

I am using AngularJS and 'have included jQuery in it which is not working in HTML page. Why does this happen?

```js
$('#setting').change(function() {
  alert("hi");
});
```

```html
<div class="content table-responsive table-full-width">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
      <th>Settings</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select id="setting" class="form-control">
            <option>---Select---</option>
            <option ng-repeat="item in settings" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
          </select>
          <div id="btn" class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 16px;">
            <input type="button" name="Activate" value="Activate" />
            <input type="button" name="Deactivate" value="Deactivate" />
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to refer jquery library in your code

Comment: Make sure the script doesn't run until the page has loaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: What do you see in your console?

Comment: Open the debugger and check the console to make sure JQuery is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead just use `ng-change` directive:

```
<select id="setting" class="form-control" ng-change='functionToCall()'>
```

and in your controller's scope object add this funciton:

```
$scope.functionToCall = function(){
   alert('hi');
};
```

---

If you have started with angularjs then its better to leave the jquery style code. Angularjs is way different than jquery.

This is good starting point.["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Answer (score 0):

This often happens when you use jQuery against DOM elements which haven't been created yet.

When your webpage loads, the Angular (probably) won't have kicked in, and populated your drop down list yet.

The solution is to use Angular's `ng-change` instead.  Then, your function *will* get kicked off when you select an item in your drop down list.

I have an example of this here:

[Angular tutorial](http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page8.5.htm)

Here, I update the customer's details whenever the user selects a new customer:

[image]

The code, to populate the list, and call a function when the selected item changes, looks like this:

```
    <select ng-model="selectedCustomer" 
      ng-change="loadOrders();" 
      ng-options="customer as customer.CompanyName for customer in listOfCustomers" >
    </select>
```